# Converting decimal to twos-complement, overflow

Tags: binary, twos-complement

I need to convert the number 200 into a two-complement 8-bit, but I can only get the result 011001000, which is 9-bit, is this an error in my textbook or is there some other way?

Comment: You can only represent signed values between -128 and 127 in 8 bits, if that's what you mean.

Answer (score 0):

200 is outside the range for 8-bit two's-complement integers.  Because you only get 7 bits for magnitude (the first bit is the sign), the maximum positive value you can put into an 8-bit two's complement integer is `(2**7 - 1) = 127`

You need at least nine bits to represent 200 in two's complement.